# Code Completion for Storyboard Identifiers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

It's a pain to copy and paste the identifier names from one place to another. Is there a way to activate the code completion for identifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to activate code completion for Storyboard Identifiers as they are NSString objects. However, as an alternative you could create a constants file to house all the identifiers and code completion would work fine on the constants.

**Example**:

Say you have the following StoryBoard Identifiers: FirstViewController, SecondViewController & SomeSegue.

You could create the a file called EXStoryBoardIdenfiers.h to house these:

```
// 
// EXStoryBoardIdentifiers.h
// 
// Created by Example Programmer on 12/14/12.
// 

#define kStoryBoardIdentifierFirstViewController @"FirstViewController"
#define kStoryBoardIdentifierSecondViewController @"SecondViewController"
#define kStoryBoardIdentifierSomeSegue @"SomeSegue"
```

Then just import this file where ever you need to access these identifiers to get code completion for them.

Comment: Looks like there really isn't a way to do the completion. Thanks for the nice tip and snipped though.

Comment: This method is exactly what I use too. But still I miss code completion within Interface Builder